# Why can't ECS containers using `awsvpc` network mode declare `extraHosts` in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I'd like to be able to declare additional hosts for my docker container in CloudFormation using the [`extraHosts`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#ContainerDefinition-extraHosts) directive. Unfortunately, since I'm using Fargate this is impossible because Fargate always uses `awsvpc` network mode.

Why is it impossible to declare extra entries in a container's hosts file when in `awsvpc` mode? Is it not just a simple extra call too `--add-host` behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWSVPC mode is a custom model that does not use the standard container based docker flags. In other words they need to be re-implemented at the "task" level (available for all containers inside the task) and we simply haven't implemented this flag (along with others such as `searchDomains`).

In a side projects of mine I have worked around this by starting the container with a script that reads a variable and configure the container itself. The file is [here](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/blob/master/yelb-appserver/startup.sh) and I am copy/pasting it here for convenience:

```
#!/bin/bash

# when the variable is populated a search domain entry is added to resolv.conf at startup
# this is needed for the ECS service discovery given the app works by calling host names and not FQDNs
# a search domain can't be added to the container when using the awsvpc mode 
# and the awsvpc mode is needed for A records (bridge only supports SRV records)
if [ $SEARCH_DOMAIN ]; then echo "search ${SEARCH_DOMAIN}" >> /etc/resolv.conf; fi 

ruby /app/yelb-appserver.rb -o 0.0.0.0)
```

There are additional discussions on the topic in this [GH issue](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1076).